# When I am deploying war file in Tomcat 6 ,from manager its showing :Deploy Upload Failed,

Tags: tomcat

Exception: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\work\Catalina\localhost\manager\upload_00000000.tmp (Access is denied)

Answer (score 1):

Give Full-Control permission to the user on Tomcat 6.0 folder.